# how to fill an array with data(String) from firebase

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm unable to fill an array with data(strings) from firebase.
The received data isn't null, I check it in debug. This is the code:

```
 func getdatesVIsitesValues()->Void{

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let visiteRef = self.ref.child("visites/visite")
    visiteRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: {(snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children{
            let thisVisite = MyVsiteModel.init(data: child as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            if(thisVisite.meetingDate.isEmpty){
                print("empty", "empty")
            }else{
               self.visitesArray.insert(thisVisite.meetingDate, atIndex: 0)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I use this method for testing the array:

```
 func testvisite()->Void{
         print("testarray count",  visitesArray.count)
        for (index,element) in visitesArray.enumerate() {
            print("\(index) = \(element)")
        }
     }
```

ps: the call of those two methods is at the end of **viewDidLoad()** method.

Comment: Could it be a problem of threading?

Comment: Put the `testvisite()` call **in** the completion block since FireBase requests work asynchronously.

Comment: @vadian thank you a lot, it's working now

Comment: Good call @vadian. Can you write that into a (short) answer? Otherwise we have few options but closing the question, which feels odd.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since FireBase requests – like almost all network requests – work asynchronously,
put the `testvisite()` call **in** the completion block.